# Select set variable value in SSH session

Tags: linux, ssh, shell

I'm writing a shell script. It will run from machine A, which will SSH into machine B and prompt the user to select a build folder. It'll then copy it to machine A, but I don't know how I can have the user select the folder to be copied?

```
install_master() {
  ssh -t -t $DEV_UNAME@$DEVSOURCE << EOF
  cd $BUILD_DIR
  ls

  ?? need the code which would select the folder and scp it 

  scp -r $BUILD_FOLDER $USER@$MASTER_NODE:/var/tmp
  exit
  EOF
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just take the folder path from the user input:

```
read BUILD_FOLDER
```

A curses file-selector that outputs the selection would be ideal, but I did not find one when I did a quick Google search. Your best bet might be a graphical SCP client like WinSCP or [a linux equivalant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299412/is-there-any-winscp-equivalent-for-linux).